# Is my encryption safe as openPGP/SMIME?

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl

I'm trying to write a simple file enc/decryption within a larger project.
I'd like to avoid libgpgme because of license issues. The openPGP standard is to complex for the project timeframe i have.
I'd like to do my encryption stuff with openssl.

Now i've implemented the following:

encryption (pseude code):

```
RAND_bytes(aes_key)
RAND_bytes(aes_salt)

EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), (const unsigned char *)aes_salt, aes_key, sizeof(aes_key), 5, key, iv);
```

then i aes256 my data

```
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&e_ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
```

then i encrypt the key and iv with RSA

```
RSA_public_encrypt(flen, (unsigned char *)key, encryptedKey, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING );
RSA_public_encrypt(flen, (unsigned char *)iv, encryptedIV, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING );
```

then i save the 128bit key and iv at the "top" of my file (256Bytes header).

decryption:
-> read the first 256bytes (split into key and iv)
-> decrypt the key and iv with the local RSA Private Key (of course the RSA Private Key IS NOT in the file)
-> use the key and iv to decrypt the data

Am i kind of safe with that code?

Comment: Safe from what? Any one can do an encryption scheme they can't break themselves. The question is whether your threat source is Aunt Mabel trying to look up a recipe on the interwebitubes, or the NSA getting in an reading your Star Trek fanfic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the OpenSSL envelope-encryption functions anyway, you should just directly use the `EVP_SealInit()` / `EVP_SealUpdate()` / `EVP_SealFinal()` functions.   These functions take care of generating the symmetric key and IV, encrypting the data with the symmetric key and encrypting the symmetric key with the recipient(s) RSA key(s).

Once thing that you are not taking care of is authenticity.  Under CBC mode it is possible for an attacker to make certain predictable changes to the plaintext, even if they can't read it.  To detect this, you should either calculate a HMAC over the encrypted message (using a seperate symmetric key to that used for encryption), or sign the encrypted message (eg. with `EVP_SignInit()` / `EVP_SignUpdate()` / `EVP_SignFinal()`).

Comment: Thanks! I did not know EVL_SealInit (and friends). I've just implemented it and it looks much proper than my way in the original question.

Comment: @caf you said: "These functions take care of generating the symmetric key and IV" , are you sure that the IV is generated too? I couldn't find any information about this. As I know only the key for the symmetric alorithm is generate (like des3, aes..)

Comment: @FatihArslan: Yes, I am certain that it generates the IV - this is what the documentation says, and I have double-checked in the code.  `EVP_SealInit()` calls `RAND_pseudo_bytes(iv, EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(ctx))`

Comment: @caf thanks for the info. I've created an wrapper around RAND_pseudo_bytes to create iv code. It seems I don't to seed the function with this. Giving `NULL` for `IV` argument is just the same. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a new format, you should use OAEP padding. Just change `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING` to `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`. You actually don't need to encrypt the IV (it can't hurt as far as I can tell, and it might help).

Otherwise, this method should be fine so long as `RSA_size(rsa)==16`. Of course, the private key must not be knowable by anyone who should not be able to decrypt the file.

Answer (score 2):

Encryption is a topic where things are easy to make "work" - but *hard* to make secure. When in doubt (and doubly so when *not* in doubt), pick a widely recognized standard and *implement precisely to spec*. The idea of encrypting the key with a public-private algorithm, then packing the IV in as well is sound in theory, but I'm not sure what the implications of encrypting the IV as well are, and what happens if the attacker starts flipping bits in the encrypted data? Etc. It *looks* sound, but again, I would strongly recommend simply implementing a published spec *precisely*.

I would recommend just implementing [S/MIME](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3851), using a binary transfer encoding. S/MIME is recognized as being a secure specification, there are [libraries implementing all the hard parts](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/smime/), and most importantly, you can test your implementation against other implementations to make sure you're not out of spec.

Comment: the problem with SMIME are large files. SMIME is (as far as i know) not suitable for >1GB files. What do you think?

Comment: @JonasSchnelli, I'm not aware of any fundamental limitation there. You'll want to use a binary transport encoding to avoid the overhead from base64, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

- The `EVP_BytesToKey` function is meant to create a key and initialization vector from a password and salt, not from random data. It will work, but you could also simply use the random bytes directly as key and initialization vector. (Make sure you are using a secure PRNG, I'm not sure what `RAND_bytes` actually does.)
- The initialization vector does not need to be secret, CBC mode should be secure with a non-encrypted IV. (This does not hurt, though.)
- The RSA encryption looks good (but you might want to use another padding, as David said).
- As Serdalis said, you should also protect your file against modifications. Any keyed MAC will do (most common are HMAC build on a key and a hash function). Apply the MAC after encryption.

Comment: Thanks! Yes. HMAC is fine. I use the sha-1(hexbytes) of the as filename.