# Open source or otherwise pgp/gpg library for Android/iphone/ipad

Tags: android, iphone, pgp

This is probably time-sensitive, unless there's a project currently providing a standard.

Is there a tested library for android and iOS that provides a PGP/GPG implementation for decrypting data received over a web-request?

I am looking to secure data transferred over SSL such that it's written to the disk in an encrypted form in the specific event of device theft or jailbreaking.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in one of my projects and i did solve it with openssl and with a own encryption.

Mainly because...

1. there is no Android/iOS (c or c++) capable PGP/GPG framework.
2. the only one reasonable framework i found is [GPGME](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/) which is under GNU license (not okay for iOS!)
3. with openssl it's not that difficult as i was thinking it is. :)

You need to take a closer look at the EVP openssl crypto function, ... especially 
`EVP_SealInit()` / `EVP_SealUpdate()` / `EVP_SealFinal()`

You then can also look at one of [my stackoverflow question regarding the encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868754/is-my-encryption-safe-as-openpgp-smime).

Goog luck!

Comment: My first thought was - well what if I opened a github project on it? But, I doubt I'd have the time.  If someone wants some light funding on making an appropriate framework, I'd consider that.  I think your post is a little over my experience level, so I'm going to hunt for a dev unless you're hirable :) ?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you can easily now use [UNNetPGP](https://github.com/upnext/unnetpgp). It's based on NetBSD library netpgp, and very easy to deploy with Cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can use a repackaged version of bouncycastle. You need a repackaged version because there is an incomplete version already in Android.