# IOS file encryption

Tags: ios, ipad, security

We found out that a third party software tool can get complete access to the ipad filesystem via the USB port without any restriction (encryption or password)
You can view and copy any file on the iPad. No jailbreak is neeeded.
Has anyone worked with file encryption on the ipad so we could encrypt files we want to secure?

I must say that Apple does not mention anything and does not acknowledge that non-apple software can bypass all the apple security with ease.

Are there any encryption libraries/apis I might use to encrypt let's say PDF files so they cannot be opened when copied from the ipad?

We mostly work with Adobe Air to create simple IOS apps. Are there any file security options to use with it?

Answer (score 0):

In some points you are right.

1) if the device is unlocked (the pin/password was entered) or the device does not have a unlock pin/password, then the files are unencrypted accessible with [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) and co.

2) you can add an additional encryption with openssl... look at my older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868754/is-my-encryption-safe-as-openpgp-smime) or check SMIME function of openssl.